# How do I comment out php to add a HTML form within a php print?

Tags: php, html, sql

Here is my code, works fine and prints out everything I want it to. But on the end of each cell I would like a form that makes a button which will allow the user to configure the item that the row in the table describes. I want to know how I can escape out of php to use html again, I've tried double quotes but this does not work, I was wondering if anyone could explain to me how to do this.

```
<?php
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basestation WHERE email_address ='$email'") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     Print "<table border = 1>"; 
     while( $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ) ) { 
       Print "<tr>"; 
       Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['base_station_id'] . "</td>";
       Print "</tr>"; 
       Print "<tr>";  
       Print "<th>Serial Number:</th> <td>".$info['serial_no'] . "</td> "; 
       Print "</tr>"; 
     } 
     Print "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I'm afraind your question is not obvious enough. You should try to ask more clearly to increase chance of getting clear answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP code will only being executed between the opening `<?php` and the closing `?>` php tags. However you are free to use multiple php sections per file.

So, you can just close the PHP section using `?>` . Then after writing HTML content you can open `<?php` again.

Here comes a little example. It creates a couple of `<a>` achors from an imaginal array `$links`:

```
<?php

foreach($links as $link) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link['href']; ?>"><?php echo $link['title'];?></a>
<?php }
```

Note that this mostly leads to unreadable code. But it is possible and can be used.

Also not that there is short syntax available for shorter echo syntax. But you'll have to make sure that it is enabled in your php configuration. Using the shorter syntax, may example from above could look like this:

```
foreach($links as $link) { ?>
    <a href="<?=$link['href']?>"><?=$link['title'];?></a>
<? }
```

You'll find a good documentation on the [PHP website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Comment: Thanks, first time I've asked a question on here and it was answered in no time.

Comment: :) don't hesitate to ask questions

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the PHP delimiters `<?php` and `?>`. Use these to switch back to HTML within the document also.

```
<?php
  function foo(bar) {
    return bar == 1 ? 'bar' : 'nobar';
  }

?>
<h1>Heading with just HTML</h1>
<div class="<?php print foo(1); ?>">This is a div with a dynamic class.</div>
<?php
  // and php again
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a link to a page with the `id` in the `url`

```
Print "<tr>";  
Print "<th>Edit:</th><td><a href='edit.php?id='".$info['id'].">Edit</a></td> "; 
Print "</tr>";
```

Then on `edit.php` you can get the id (`$_GET['id']`) and query the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basestation WHERE email_address ='$email'") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     Print "<table border = 1>"; 
     while( $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ) ) { 
       Print "<tr>"; 
       Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['base_station_id'] . "</td>";
       Print "</tr>"; 
       Print "<tr>";  
       Print "<th>Serial Number:</th> <td>".$info['serial_no'] . "</td> ";
 ?> 
       <-- form here --->
 <?php
       Print "</tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>";
?>
```